# Are appliance-related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I think someone asked this on the commitment phrase, but I do not remember the responses.

Are we going to allow questions related to appliances?

An example could it be:

> Which washer/dryer allows me to control it using my smartphone?

In this case, it is asking for a appliance, but the feature of "control it using a smartphone" might be on topic.

Comment: This is something we'll have to figure out - what *is* hardware?

Comment: See also [What type of hardware is allowed?](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-type-of-hardware-is-allowed) (not a duplicate, it's going to take several specific cases to figure it out)

Answer (score 3):

Based on our core audience and the community building this site, I would expect "hardware" to be directly related to technology or computing devices to some degree. In reality, this is more of a "technology recommendations" site than something directly related to computers; but it is generally understood that such hardware includes peripherals and similarly associated devices. How far you want to extend that association is up to you… but I don't generally see this including "non technology" products like hammers, saws, and other tools you typically find in your "hardware store" <grin>.

Comment: To be fair, the "directly related to computing devices" is the tricky part, as more and more technology is being integrated with computers/smartphones/etc (such as the examples above, or smart thermostats, etc).

Comment: This opens up the "Is home automation advice allowed?" question which in most instances involve appliances and the like.