# Laser cutters on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm likely going to be in the market for a laser cutter with significant ability to be controlled from my computer (my computer capability will limit what I can do with it). It'll definitely have a computer/processor on it.

This seems borderline, but would a question like this be on topic here?

[This suggests yes](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/77/6) but I'm curious.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds [on topic](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware).

I think it falls under this section of the "on topic" answer:

> Hardware is any primarily electronic item that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, a primary computing platform in day-to-day operation.

That way you've described it, this sounds like such a piece of hardware interfaces with the computer to perform precision work.